# Sufficient condition for $E[X^kY]=E[X^k]E[Y] \forall k\ge 0$

Tags: probability

I wonder to find a sufficient condition that leads to the following:
$E[X^kY]=E[X^k]E[Y] \forall k\ge 0$
where $X$ and $Y$ are random variables. An obvious sufficient condition is that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, but such a condition might be too strong. Is there a weaker sufficient condition (commonly used in probability theory)? Thank you!

Comment: This condition is equivalent to $E[Y\mid X]=E[Y]$.

Comment: The condition $E[Y|X] = E[Y]$ is sufficient, but probably not necessary. You may find counter-examples involving random variables $X$ whose law is not determined by the moments $(E[X^k])_{k \ge 0}$.

Comment: Thank you! But I have not figured out how to prove it. Could you give me some tips? Many thanks! Furthermore, I guess that $E[Y|X]=E[Y]$ may imply that for all functions $f$ with some technical assumptions, $E[f(x)Y]=E[f(X)]E[Y]$ will hold. Is it correct?